# Security implications of allowing 'https' in CSP connect-src

Tags: content-security-policy

What are the security implications of allowing 'https' for 'connect-src' in my CSP?

I understand that an attacker would technically be able to send information to any URL (though not sure how), but given that I restrict script-src with a nonce I would assume it is not possible for an attacker to execute any code. The only exception could be an extension in the client browser, which can execute code if it has permissions by the user and then be able to send information from my webpage to their server. Or are there any other ways for an attacker to send information using connect-src?

Answer (score 0):

Not restricting connect-src means there are more ways of exfiltrating data available. An attacker could always use query string parameters of unrestricted directives for this, but leaving connect-src open provides more possibilities. Thoughts on this in the scope of script code in css files is discussed in https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/.

Automated security analyzers will also point out that connect-src permissions are wide and could flag it as a problem without being able to analyze the entire policy.